# How To Create The Loop Cut Effect on Triangles and Other Non-quadrilateral Faces

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I have this image below of a model with a Selected triangle face, I want to create a vertical cut that will allow me to move the UV for the left side of the face.

[image]

I know you can only loop-cut on quadrilateral shapes only. So how would I cut this shape in half? Can I do something like this in the UV editor?

I tried using the knife tool but the line I created kept disappearing every time I picked both my edges.

Comment: You have to press enter when the knifetool selection is done

Comment: @WhatAMesh The line disappears after I select the top point of triangle and the bottom middle. The line only stays if I make cutting points inside the face.

Comment: Select the "bottom" edge, right click and select "subdivide" to put a vertex in the center of it. Then select that vertex, as well as vertex at the "top" of the triangle. and press J (join).

Comment: That did it, cheers